# Bounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a question about a operator.

Let $d \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\gamma>d$. For $f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$, we define $T:L^2(\mathbb{R}^{d}) \to L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ by
\begin{align*}
Tf(x)=\int_{ \{y \in \mathbb{R}^{d}\,:\, |x-y|>1\}}\frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{\gamma}}dy\quad({\rm a.e.}\,x \in \mathbb{R}^{d})
\end{align*}

I want to show $T$ is bounded operator on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$. My approach is as follows :

$k(x,y):=\frac{1}{|x-y|^{\gamma}}$, $\Omega_{x}:=\{y \in \mathbb{R}^{d}\,:\, |x-y|>1\}$

\begin{align*}
|Tf(x)|^{2}&\leq \left(\int_{\Omega_{x}}|k(x,y)||f(y)|dy \right)^{2} \\
&=\left( \int_{\Omega_{x}}|k(x,y)|^{1/2}|k(x,y)|^{1/2}|f(y)|dy \right)^{2}\\
&\leq \int_{\Omega_{x}}|k(x,y)|dy \int_{\Omega_{x}} |k(x,y)|f(y)|^{2}dy \,(Schwarz)
\end{align*}

Cleary $\infty>\int_{\Omega_{x}}|k(x,y)|dy=:M $ (independent of $x$)

\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R^{d}}} |Tf(x)|^{2} dx &\leq M\int_{\mathbb{R^{d}}}\left[\int_{\Omega_{x}}|k(x,y)||f(y)|^{2}dy \right]dx \\
&\leq M\int_{\mathbb{R^{d}}}|k(x,y)|\left[\int_{\mathbb{R^{d}}}|f(y)|^{2}dy \right]dx \\
&=M \int_{\mathbb{R^{d}}}|f(y)|^{2}dy \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|k(x,y)|dx
\end{align*}

But $\int_{\mathbb{R^{d}}}|k(x,y)|dx=\infty$. It has gone wrong

Do you know something good inequality or evaluation? Please let me know.

Comment: I assume you are integrating over $\mathbb R^d$ but not just $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Sorry I mistyped.

Comment: Maybe treat it as a convolution with $\phi(x) = {1 \over \|x\|^\gamma} 1_{\bar{B}(0,1)^c}(x)$?

Comment: I don't have my laptop in front of me so I can not type nicely. Here is a idea, it may or may not work, but worth a try. Using the fact that $C_c^\infty$ function is dense in $L^2$ and work on $f\in C_c^\infty$ first, which can give you some benefit for example never worry about infinity.

Comment: See Young's inequality for convolutions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I’ll give it a try.

Comment: Thanks. I could solve this problem by using $\phi$ as above and Young's inequality.